# How do I use javascript onmouseover function with svg to get classname?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, classname

I have a SVG map where I would like to change the text on a side panel when a certain area of the map is moused over. I want to change the text to the classname of the anchor containing the area being moused over. Currently, whenever I mouse over the map, it returns undefined in the side panel.

I tried setting the code to only function if the classname was not equal to nil, and the function did not fire, so I must not be getting the anchor tag on mouse over.

HTML (removed irrelevant code)

```
<p onmouseover="houseQuickOverview()">
    <svg ... >
        <g id="G_Areas" ... >
            <a class="HD-002" ... >
                <path gg:cat="2" d="M ... />
            </a>
            <a class="HD-003" ... >
                <path gg:cat="2" d="M ... />
            </a>
```

JavaScript

```
let houseQuickOverview = function () {
        let district = this.className;
        document.querySelector(".districtNumber").innerHTML = district;

}
```

When I mouse over the paragraph, which contains the SVG, when the mouse touches one of the anchors, I want it to return the classname of the anchor to the districtNumber div. It currently only returns undefined to the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below and in your specific case, you may need to narrow down els like this

`const anchor = document.querySelectorAll("p a"); // to select only <a> under <p>`

```js
(function() {
  const anchor = document.querySelectorAll("a")
  for (const a of anchor) {
    a.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = event.currentTarget.className;
    })
  }
})();
```

```css
#result {
  color: red;
}

a {
  display: block;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<a class="HD-002">
                123
            </a>
<a class="HD-0022">
                456
            </a>
<a class="HD-0023">
                789
            </a>
<a class="HD-0024">
                101112
            </a>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: ```document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = event.currentTarget.innerHTML;``` When I change the last innerHTML to className, I get [object SVGAnimatedString] for my result

Comment: I dont have your svg, so can you show some example how to reproduce?

Comment: I figured out the problem, it seems that for some reason the classnames of elements that are within a SVG tag can't be accessed by .className, but they must be referenced by .className.baseVal or .target.getAttribute("class"). Thanks for the help!